# Apple accounts and a workplace Mac?

Tags: apple-id

I am getting a MacBook Pro today, in order to build an App.

My question is simple (I hope):

- Can I set up a company account through Apple, for Appstore purchases, etc.?

Or?

- Do I have to set up a personalized account?

Bear in mind that in the future, I might not be the person that works on future apps, so the machine might transition over to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup an account for a company, just use a company e-mail address that isn't strictly your own (ideally, something generic like appleid@company) and fill out the correct fields on the sign-up section.

You can also use this account to join the developer program with Apple - although this might be what you meant anyway.

When signing up, I'd still use your name - this can easily be changed, but fill out the company details (and, I suppose, credit card).